# Basic HttpRelayBinding for .Net Core

Tags: azure, wcf, .net-core, azureservicebus

I have a .Net Core 2 app that needs to call a WCF service. I've been able to add connected service and it consumed the WSDL ok. My problem is, the call needs to be made via Azure Service Bus Relay.

I realise that the MS docs suggest .Neg Core clients use "Hybrid Connections" instead of WCF Relay but I have a BizTalk 2016 app listening at the other side of the WCF Relay, waiting to return data to the client. As far as I can tell, there is no capability for BizTalk to work with Hybrid Connections.

In .Net core it seems the only option for the WCF client is to configure via code (no app.config or equivalent). I can use the following:

```
svc.Endpoint.Binding = new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding(System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpSecurityMode.None);
```

However, there is no System.ServiceModel.BasicHttp**Relay**Binding? Has anyone managed to make calls to the Azure Service Bus Relay from .Net Core?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this problem and blogged about it here: [BizTalk and the Hybrid Connection Manager](https://biztalkersblog.azurewebsites.net/calling-on-prem-biztalk-from-azure/)